# Why is the map $I$ from subsets of $\mathbb{A}_k^n$ to ideals of $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ not surjective?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In algebraic geometry, we consider the map

$$I:\{\text{subsets of }\mathbb{A}_k^n\}\longrightarrow\{\text{ideals of }k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]\},\qquad X\mapsto I(X)$$

This map is not injective, because $I(\mathbb{A_k^n})=0$. But why it is not surjective? How to find a counterexample? Thank you!

Comment: Can - in general - $I(X)^2$ be of the form $I(Y)$?

Comment: The observation that $I(\mathbb{A}_k^n) = 0$ doesn't show that the map is not injective. You need to find some other subset $S\subsetneq \mathbb{A}_k^n$ with $I(S) = 0$ for that. $I$ is not a group homomorphism!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Suppose that $x_1^2$ vanishes on a subset $S\subseteq \mathbb{A}_k^n$. What other polynomial can you deduce vanishes on the subset $S$ as well? Can the ideal $(x_1^2)\subset k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ be $I(S)$ for any $S$, then?

Answer (score 3):

The image consists precisely of the [radical ideals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_ideal).